# Number of ways to color N objects in X colors where there is at least one object of each color.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

What is the number of way to color $N$ objects in $X$ colors, where there is at least 1 object of each color?

Comment: In other words, you want the number of surjections from a set of size $N$ to a set of size $X$. If you know what "Stirling numbers of the second kind" are, use them. Otherwise, use the in-and-out principle.

Comment: Got my answer... add in answer please?

Comment: are the objects distinguishable? I assume the colors are.

Comment: Each object is distinguishable. Each color is distinguishable.I am thinking, starling(n,k)*k! can be the answer.